# No video (only sound) on TextureView inside viewPager

Tags: android-viewpager, textureview

I'm trying to show a video or an image inside a viewpager which is an item of a listview.
While the image is displaying correctly, the video just plays sound, with no video.
I've tried using VideoView and also SurfaceView with no luck.
I'd rather not use fragments for this.

In the listview I'm loading a bunch of images and a single video, for test reasons.
The images load up fine, but the video only plays sound.

I think it has something to do with it not setting its surfaceTexture correctly but I cant figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
public class MediaSliderPagerAdapter2 extends PagerAdapter {
    private int forListItem = -1;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    private SurfaceTexture mVideoSurfaceTexture;

    public MediaSliderPagerAdapter2(int forListItem, LayoutInflater inflater) {
        super();
        this.forListItem = forListItem;
        this.inflater = inflater;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        boolean isVideo = false;
        String url = "";

        try {
            isVideo = mMediaUrls.get(forListItem).get(position).isVideo;
            url = mMediaUrls.get(forListItem).get(position).url;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("getUrlType", e.getMessage());
        }

        if(!url.equals("")){
            if(isVideo) {                   


                final View layoutAll = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pager_video, container, false);
                layoutAll.setId(R.id.feedlist_viewpager_layout_id_base + (position+1)*(1000*forListItem+1));

                container.addView(layoutAll);

                final TextureView layout = (TextureView) layoutAll.findViewById(R.id.videoView_layout);

                mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);


                layout.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);
                layoutAll.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);

                layout.setSurfaceTextureListener(new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
                        Surface s = new Surface(surface);

                        mVideoSurfaceTexture = surface;

                        Log.i("height-width:", height+"-"+width);
                        try {
                            mMediaPlayer.setSurface(s);
                            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4");
                            mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

                            mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener()  {
                                @Override
                                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

                                    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(mContext);
                                    mediaController.setAnchorView(layout);
                                    mediaController.setMediaPlayer(new MediaController.MediaPlayerControl() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void start() {
                                            mMediaPlayer.start();
                                        }
                                        @Override
                                        public void pause() {
                                            mMediaPlayer.pause();
                                        }
                                        @Override
                                        public int getDuration() {
                                            return mMediaPlayer.getDuration();
                                        }
                                        @Override
                                        public int getCurrentPosition() {
                                            return mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                                        }
                                        @Override
                                        public void seekTo(int pos) {
                                            mMediaPlayer.seekTo(pos);
                                        }
                                        @Override
                                        public boolean isPlaying() {
                                            return mMediaPlayer.isPlaying();
                                        }
                                        @Override
                                        public int getBufferPercentage() {
                                           return 0;
                                        }
                                        @Override
                                        public boolean canPause() {
                                            return true;
                                        }
                                        @Override
                                        public boolean canSeekBackward() {
                                            return true;
                                        }
                                        @Override
                                        public boolean canSeekForward() {
                                            return true;
                                        }
                                        @Override
                                        public int getAudioSessionId() {
                                            return mMediaPlayer.getAudioSessionId();
                                        }
                                    });

                                    mediaController.show(99999);
                                    Log.i("VideoView", "Duration = " + mMediaPlayer.getDuration() + " height-width:" + layout.getHeight() + "-" + layout.getWidth());

                                    mMediaPlayer.start();
                                }
                            });
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
                        Log.e("SurfaceSizeChanged", width+"/"+height);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {
                        boolean isNull = surface==null;
                        Log.e("onSurfaceTextureUpdated", "isNull: "+ isNull);
                    }
                });



                return layoutAll.getId();
            }
            else {
                final ImageView layout = (ImageView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pager_image, null);
                layout.setId(R.id.feedlist_viewpager_layout_id_base + (position+1)*(1000*forListItem+1));

                layout.setImageBitmap(null);
                layout.clearAnimation();
                Ion.with(mContext)
                        .load(url)
                        .withBitmap()
                        .smartSize(true)
                        .disableFadeIn()
                        .animateIn(R.anim.fade_in_)
                        .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.loading)
                        .animateLoad(R.anim.spin_animation)
                        .intoImageView(layout);

                container.addView(layout);
                return layout.getId();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }



    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        View view = container.findViewById((Integer) object);

        if(view instanceof ImageView) {
            ((ImageView) view).setImageBitmap(null);
            view.clearAnimation();
        }
        else if(view instanceof FrameLayout) {

        }

        container.removeView(view);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        int ret = 0;

        if(mMediaUrls.get(forListItem)!= null)
            ret = mMediaUrls.get(forListItem).size();

        return ret;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object obj) {

        boolean isEqual = view.getId() == (Integer) obj;
        return isEqual;
    }




}
```

Also, the xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <FrameLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#0000">

    <com.camboindustries.picabet.adapters.SquareTextureView
        android:id="@+id/videoView_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#0000">
    </com.camboindustries.picabet.adapters.SquareTextureView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: If you comment out the video play code and just render onto the TextureView with canvas, do you see anything?  That would tell you if the problem is with the video rendering or with the display of the TextureView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@fadden : thanks for the help, but it turned out to be a problem with my SquareTextureView custom View:

I had changed the onMeasure function to this:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int width, int height) {
    super.onMeasure(width, height);
    int measuredWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
    setMeasuredDimension(measuredWidth, measuredWidth);
}
```

which I think was the root of the problem.

I created a SquareFrameLayout custom view with the same modification and it is now ok...

I'm not sure why that happened (if someone knows the answer feel free to comment so we can learn something from this) but I'm just glad it worked :)